# How to provide a suffix to Vim 8 when building on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim, make, build

I'm trying to build Vim 8.0 on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS. 
`configure` and `make` run without any errors, however it does ignore the parameter `--program-suffix`:

```
[local vim repo]/configure --program-suffix=8 --with-features=big
```

I intended to build Vim 8.0 parallel to my stable setup with the suffix "8", so there should be a binary `vim8` in `/usr/local/bin/`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I confirmed this behavior on CentOS 7.2 with a pull from the vim repo today (ver 8.0.3); the value from `--program-suffix` did not get stored. It is a field in the file `src/auto/configure` and after running `./configure` should populate a field in `src/config.mk` but there is no placeholder for it. The other configuration flags supplied to `configure` do update `src/config.mk`

There is a note in the file `src/INSTALL` on the topic:

> If the package supports it, you can cause programs to be installed
>   with an extra prefix or suffix on their names by giving `configure`
>   the option `--program-prefix=PREFIX` or `--program-suffix=SUFFIX`

I guess ignoring the argument and not reporting it is how the vim devs have decided to 'not support' this option in the master branch.

In order to prevent potentially overwriting files from your 7.x install, I suggest installing it to another directory entirely until you are to fully transition; if you combine that option with the renaming of vim using @pibarnas suggested flag, you can isolate the vim8 installation entirely from the existing install.

```
 ./configure --with-features=big --prefix=$HOME --with-vim-name=vim8
```

Change $HOME to whatever path works for you; what I suggest is that post install you create symlinks from $HOME/bin/ to /usr/local/sbin/

```
sudo ln -s /home/<username>/bin/vim8 /usr/local/bin/
```

You can do the same with the related vim executables depending on what you build. Some of them do not take on the vim-name provided in the configuration,  which is another reason to just use a separate installation directory.

For the record, here are the binaries installed by vim. I used different configuration args; I posted that at the bottom  - just in case in an attempt to reproduce the above command doesn't work for some obscure reason; below is what I actually used.

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root    143 Sep 12 23:04 gvim8tutor
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root    19K Sep 12 23:04 xxd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root      4 Sep 12 23:04 vim8diff -> vim8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root      4 Sep 12 23:04 rview -> vim8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root      4 Sep 12 23:04 rvim8 -> vim8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root      4 Sep 12 23:04 view -> vim8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root      4 Sep 12 23:04 ex -> vim8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root      4 Sep 12 23:04 gvim8diff -> vim8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root      4 Sep 12 23:04 eview -> vim8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root      4 Sep 12 23:04 evim8 -> vim8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root      4 Sep 12 23:04 rgview -> vim8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root      4 Sep 12 23:04 rgvim8 -> vim8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root      4 Sep 12 23:04 gview -> vim8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root      4 Sep 12 23:04 gvim8 -> vim8
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root   2.1K Sep 12 23:04 vim8tutor
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root   2.7M Sep 12 23:04 vim8
```

Vim config / build / install command:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME --with-vim-name=vim8 --with-compiledby="argonauts12" --with-features=huge --enable-gui=auto --with-x --enable-rubyinterp --with-ruby-command=/usr/bin/ruby --enable-perlinterp --enable-pythoninterp --with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib64/python2.7/config --enable-fontset --enable-cscope --enable-gtk2-check --enable-gnome-check --enable-fail-if-missing --disable-multibyte && make -j8 && make install
```

Answer (score 1):

Accordingly to ./config --help:

--with-vim-name=NAME    what to call the Vim executable

In the case:

--with-vim-name=vim8